# Checking against Nltk POS tags

Tags: nltk

I am just learning nltk using Python. I am using POS tagging. What I want to know is how do I use the tags. For example, this is the pseudocode:

```
words = []
teststr = "George did well in the test."
tokens = nltk.word_tokenize(teststr)
words = nltk.pos_tag(tokens)
```

I want to do something like this:

```
if words[i] == "proper noun":
    #do something
```

How do I check whether a word is a noun or a verb or any other part of speech.
Can someone please help me out here?
Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you look at the results of your pos_tag function call you are returned the following list:

```
[('George', 'NNP'), ('did', 'VBD'), ('well', 'RB'), ('in', 'IN'), ('the', 'DT'), ('test', 'NN'), ('.', '.')]
```

If you iterate through the list to do something based on the value being a proper noun you would need the following code:

```
if words[i][1] == 'NNP':
    # do something
```

NNP is a singular proper noun. Each entry in that list is a tuple which the first value being the word and the second value being the pos.

Comment: Thanks a lot Ryan! I get it now. Sorry, no reputation so can't upvote.